# Excel: Creating recursive dates in table with calculated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a currency rate table with Date, GBP rate, EUR rate and a (calculated) WEEKDAY values. But the data only runs weekdays.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snFyq.png)

I'd like to extend the table so that the Date range is continuous (i.e. Mon to Sun) and the GBP and EUR fields are filled such that if it's a Saturday it takes the value from Friday and if it's a Sunday it takes the following Monday value.

To produce:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp0zR.png)

I've tried XLOOKUP's with IFS but am a bit stumped as to whether I need a lambda function to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inserting Weekends

- This is a brute-force solution with excessive stacking. Its efficiency may be questionable. Your feedback is welcome and expected.
- Adjust the table name.

```
=LET(Data,Table1[#All],
    d,DROP(Data,1),mSeq,SEQUENCE(,2,2),
VSTACK(TAKE(Data,1),
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(cr,INDEX(d,r),
        IF(INDEX(d,r,4)=5,
            VSTACK(rr,cr,HSTACK(INDEX(cr,,1)+1,INDEX(cr,,mSeq),INDEX(cr,,4)+1)),
        IF(INDEX(d,r,4)=1,
            VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(INDEX(cr,,1)-1,INDEX(cr,,mSeq),INDEX(cr,,4)+6),cr),
        VSTACK(rr,cr)))))),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. It works for me as its a small dataset. I wish i could understand better the formula. i wrongly imagined it would have been simpler but guess inserting new rows adds complexity. Thanks anyway.